# Putty windows not displaying

Tags: windows-vista, putty

This problem has occurred starting this morning. I haven't changed any display settings, updated putty, I hadn't even rebooted until trouble shooting.

Running Putty release 0.63 Vista Business OS.

When I open Putty, it displays on the task bar, however not on the screen. I've made sure the windows is not off the screen, when you right click task bar icon, click move, spacebar, arrow key it moves the cursor to the middle of the screen.

I removed all the reg entries and downloaded a new putty.exe even though I'm running the latest version. Same issue.

I've done the obligatory googling, doesn't look like a known bug.

Has anyone seen this?

Comment: Until you find a solution, Try using an alternative to putty, MobaXterm http://tecadmin.net/top-5-ssh-clients-for-windows-alternatives-of-putty/ On second thoughts, have you tried Alt-Tab? May just put focus on the putty window, or are you using multiple/ extended screens? Check your display properties.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions it is a single display computer.  Alt tab does not help.  When using move space bar arrow kwy to focus the pointer on the window the Pointer appears is in the center of the screen

Comment: Can you access the rest of the putty menu from task bar?  Can you enable Alt-Enter to full-screen, and try that?

Comment: SOLUTION / WORKAROUND: This issue effects PuTTy & KiTTy. Go to 'Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization' then 'Window Color and Appearance' and change to "Windows Vista Basic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just now found that switching display settings solves the problem for me. Go to Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization and then Window Color and Appearance

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem in Vista home premium after Operating System update. I removed the updates KB3057839, KB3059317, KB3063858 and KB3033890 and now putty works properly.